# how to implement product ordering api of https://zinc.io/docs/#ordering-api

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am getting amazon products from the api. I want an api for order and payment of amazon product. After lot of search, I could only find an api at https://zinc.io/docs/#ordering-api, but I am not getting how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Varsha, can you post the code you've written so far? This will let us best assist you. The basic idea is to make an HTTP POST request to place an order, then an HTTP GET request to see its status. You can do this with the PHP cURL command.

Comment: @Doug Thanks for your reply. Actually I haven't implemented any API ever. I am not getting where to start. The code that I have is available on https://zinc.io/docs/#ordering-api

Comment: If you have never implemented an API and your application is urgent, you should consider contracting a developer with some experience integrating APIs. Alternatively, you could consider using the Zinc "File Exchange" API, which allows you to submit a simple spreadsheet for order placing. You should get in touch using the contact information on zinc.io for further assistance. Of course, this could also be a great learning experience if you would like to enhance your programming skills!